# Evaluate $\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} e^{-\left(3x^2+2 \sqrt 2 xy+3y^2\right)} \,dx\,dy$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification, multiple-integral

Evaluate $$\displaystyle\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} e^{-\left(3x^2+2 \sqrt 2 xy+3y^2\right)} \,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy\,$$

My attempt :$
3x^2+2 \sqrt 2xy+3y^2=3\left (x+\dfrac{\sqrt 2}{3}y\right )^2+y^2.$

$u=\sqrt{3}\left (x+\dfrac{\sqrt 2}{3}\right )y$ and $v=y$.
hen

$$ \mathrm du\,\mathrm dv = \left|\frac{\partial(u,v)}{\partial(x,y)}\right|\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy = \left|\begin{matrix} \sqrt 3 & 0 \\ \frac{\sqrt 3}{2}& 1 \end{matrix}\right|\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy = \sqrt 3 \,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy $$

And

$$ I = \dfrac{1}{ \sqrt3 }\iint_{\Bbb R^2} e^{-(u^2+v^2)}\, \mathrm du\,\mathrm dv $$

Switch to polar coordinates ([see solution here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral#By_polar_coordinates))

Now  my final answer is  $\dfrac{\pi}{\sqrt 3}$

Is it correct ?

Comment: 3rd line why $y$ is  outside?

Comment: $$3x^2+2\sqrt2xy+3y^2=3\left(x+\frac{\sqrt2}3y\right)^2+\frac73y^2.$$ And 
$$
\left|\frac{\partial(u,v)}{\partial(x,y)}\right|\,dx\,dy = \left|\begin{matrix} \sqrt 3 & 0 \\ \frac{\sqrt 2}{\sqrt3}& 1 \end{matrix}\right|\,dx\,dy,
$$ which does not affect the determinant though.

Comment: thanks u sir @awllower, i have  done mistake in factor

Comment: Another approach would be to orthogonally diagonalize the matrix $\begin{bmatrix} -3 & -\sqrt{2} \\ -\sqrt{2} & -3 \end{bmatrix}$ representing the quadratic form in the exponential; then with respect to the rotated coordinates $u,v$, the integral becomes $\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2} e^{\lambda_1^2 u^2 + \lambda_2^2 v^2}\,du\,dv = \sqrt{\pi/-\lambda_1} \sqrt{\pi/-\lambda_2} = \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{\lambda_1 \lambda_2}}$ - where $\lambda_1 \lambda_2$ is equal to the determinant of the original matrix, assuming $\lambda_1, \lambda_2 < 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach is right, but there are some minor mistakes in calculations.

$$
3x^2+2\sqrt2xy+3y^2=3\left (x+\frac{\sqrt2}3y\right )^2+\frac73y^2.
$$
So we take $u=\sqrt3\left (x+\dfrac{\sqrt2}3y\right )$ and $v=\dfrac{\sqrt7}{\sqrt3}y$. Then
$$
\left|\frac{\partial(u,v)}{\partial(x,y)}\right|\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy = \left|\begin{matrix} \sqrt 3 & \dfrac{\sqrt 2}{\sqrt3} \\ 0& \dfrac{\sqrt7}{\sqrt3} \end{matrix}\right|\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy.
$$

Thus the final answer should be $\dfrac\pi{\sqrt7}$.

---

Hope this helps.